# foreach error array on export pdf using html2pdf in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've never made a previous export to PDF MySQL in Codeigniter under v2. but when I switched to v3.1.0 there was a problem export to PDF in `foreach` what's wrong?

ERORR

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined offset: 1
>
> Filename: html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php

Controllers

```
public function print_data(){
    ob_start();
    $class= $this->uri->segment(3); 
    $data = array(
                    'get_data' => $this->My_model->detail_id_data($class)
    );  
    $this->load->view('print_detail_data', $data);
    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
     
    require_once('./assets/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
    $pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en', true, 'UTF-8', 3);
    $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $pdf->Output('id_detail.pdf');
}

Models

    function detail_id_data($class) {
        $query = $this->db->select('*')
                          ->from('tb_student')
                          ->where('class', $id_data)
                          ->get();
                          
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $data) {
                $hasil[] = $data;
            }
            return $hasil;
        } 
    }
```

Views

```
<table style="width: 100%; border: solid 1px black;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name </th>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Study</th>
      </tr> 
    </thead>    
    <tbody> 
    <?php 
        $no=1;
        foreach ($get_data as $row){    
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php $no; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->class; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->study; ?>f</td>        
      </tr>   
    <?php $no++; } ?>  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$id_data` in model?

Comment: its value varchar ex = class-ix. so I want to get the students there in class ix,

Comment: `where('class-xi')` like this?

Comment: but I use where based URI-> segment.

Comment: yes you have problem when rows are multiple...so using here here..

Comment: if only one row then it will be easy..

Comment: in case of multiple row u r getting problem..

Answer (score 0):

In model Use `row()` in stead of `result()`..hope it will works.

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->row()) as $data) {
                $hasil[] = $data;
            }
            return $hasil;
        }
```

Change your view like this....

```
<table style="width: 100%; border: solid 1px black;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name </th>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Study</th>
      </tr> 
    </thead>    
    <tbody> 
    <?php 
        $no=1;
        foreach ($get_data as $row){    
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php $no; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['class']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['study']; ?>f</td>        
      </tr>   
    <?php $no++; } ?>  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In controller,

Replace it..

```
 $data = array(
                    'get_data' => $this->My_model->detail_id_data($class)
    );
```

By

```
$data['get_data'] = $this->My_model->detail_id_data($class);
```

Are you getting the value of `$class`.Try below

```
echo $class;
```

Comment: You are sending `$get_data` as array.so try with this changes hope it is working.